# Prevent code from running until ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to execute an ajax call and prevent the code after it running until the ajax call has completed.

Say I have this code

```
.on('pageloadfailed', function(event){

    //if I move event.preventDefault to here the popup doesn't show. But I only want
    //to prevent the default bahaviour if the condition in the ajaxe response if met.

    $.when(ajax1()).done(function(response){
        if(resposne.success == true){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    function ajax1() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "someUrl",
            dataType: "json",
            data:  yourJsonData,            
            ...
        });
    }

    alert("test");

}
```

The alert will always fire, I only want it to fire if the code within the "when" method doesn't return false.

Thanks for the responses folks, I'll go into thing a little further.

I'm using jquery mobile. And when a page load fails jqm displays a popup telling the user to refresh. However in some instances I don't want this to happen I actually want to handle the error myself.

So when the pageloadfailed event is fired I wasn't to check something via ajax. In some cases I'll handle what happens but in other I just want to carry on.

The alert isn't actually there in my code I was just trying to use that to illustrate the point.

Comment: Have you found an adequate answer to your problem? If so, please mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

just put attribution `async` into `false`

from jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> async (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false.

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of  async: false  with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `success` and `error` callbacks:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  yourJsonData,
        success: function() {
            doSomethingOnSuccess();
        },
        error: function() {
            doSomethingOnError();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you are almost there:

```
function ajax1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  yourJsonData,            
        ...
    });
}

$.when(ajax1()).done(function(){
  alert("this should run when your AJAX call is completed. Put your code here");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use $.when() function.

```
$.when(ajaxFunction()).done(function(response){
    if(response.text != "false"){ 
        alert("test");
    }
})

function ajaxFunction() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  dataInJson,            
    });
}
```

in the code above I used response.text, but it's a guess - I don't remember how exactly does the response structure look like, you have check it yourself. All I know is that it is made of 3 parameters, and text of the response is one of them.

Comment: $.when is asynchronous function and it will not be triggered in sequence in your .on('pageloadfailed'). The event will allways be finished long BEFORE the event.preventDefault() will be trigerred.

Comment: Is there any way to preventDefault before the when and then "re-enable" it inside the condition?